# Можно ли писать modal окна не в классе а прямо в команде?

Tags: python, disnake

Я перешёл с nextcord на disnake в nextcord, я знаю как писать модальные окна не в классе отдельном, а как на disnake - не знаю.

Я бы хотел услышать как это делать а желательно увидеть маленький пример.

```
class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
def __init__(self):
    # Детали модального окна и его компонентов
    components = [
        disnake.ui.TextInput(
            label="Name",
            placeholder="Foo Tag",
            custom_id="название",
            style=TextInputStyle.short,
            max_length=50,
        ),
        disnake.ui.TextInput(
            label="Description",
            placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            custom_id="описание",
            style=TextInputStyle.paragraph,
        ),
    ]
    super().__init__(
        title="Create Tag",
        custom_id="create_tag",
        components=components,
    )

async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
    await inter.response.send_message(inter.text_values)
```